# Regarding GPIO export

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gpio

I have some basic questions around the exporting of a GPIO.

1. Regarding gpio-hog mechanism:
   The gpio-hog mechanism would help us to initialise a GPIO to either
   high/low & in/out during bootup.
   This is fine.

So my question is, if we hog a GPIO, does it also gets exported to the
userspace by default?

2. With the older sysfs interface, we would be using "echo x >
   /sys/class/gpio/export" to export the gpiox to userspace.

I wanted to know what would be the right way to do this with the newer
interface?

3. To check if a GPIO is being exported or not, we would see the
   /sys/class/gpio with the sysfs interface.

With the newer character device interface, what would be the right way
to check what GPIOs are exported to userspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [0andriy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2511795/0andriy)'s comments:

1. GPIO hog is not for that. What you describe is an (expected) side effect of using it. GPIO hog is needed to keep orphaned GPIO lines (something that OS has no driver for) in a certain states. The producer and consumer of them is the GPIO controller itself, you may not export the line which already has a consumer.
2. With new character device interface you are not supposed to export anything, you need a context for GPIO line inside your program. So, the "export" will be done inside the process, when process finishes, it automatically "unexports" all consumed GPIO lines.
3. With new interface your process will IOCTL to acquire a line handle and it will fail with error in case it's already being occupied.

Expanding a little the above...

With regard to checking what lines are currently in use, the `lsgpio` provided in [the kernel source tree](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/tools/gpio/lsgpio.c) reports that, as does the `gpioinfo` tool provided by [libgpiod](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libgpiod/libgpiod.git).

In both cases that info is intended for users.  Applications simply attempt to request a line, and that will fail with `EBUSY` if that line is already in use.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, they really helped me clearing my doubts. @Kent Gibson, I have also seen that when I hog a particular GPIO as output-low or output-high, it's always shown as "input" and "active-high" with gpioinfo. Is this expected from a hogged GPIO ? Suppose If I hog a GPIO "p13" in device tree to "output-low" and then check it with "gpioinfo chipname", it reports as "input" and "active-high"

Comment: Firstly, note that "output-low" means set the line as an output with a low physical level, which is different from active-low, and gpioinfo does not report the physical level.  
My understanding is that hog settings should be reflected in the gpioinfo output. A cursory check of the kernel code gives me no reason to think otherwise, so you would need to further debug what you are seeing to determine the root cause. e.g. a hogged line should also report as in use. Are you sure you have the correct line? Are there any lines reported in use? Are any of those output?

Comment: I agree with you. Even I looked into the kernel code, it sets the right direction of the hogged GPIO. I suspect this could be some issue with gpioinfo tool. I hog a GPIO as below pX { gpio-hog; gpios = < X 0 >; output-high; }; The gpinfo reveals following info about the GPIO: line 13: "p.X" "some_name" input active-high [used] It shows it as [used] but the direction still says input.  @Kent Gibson

Comment: @Rizwan I don't think this is the best forum to debug what you are seeing, so will reply to your thread in the GPIO mailing list.